# How to check a file is present or not in UNC path?

Tags: c#

Im trying to check the presence of the file in a UNC path using the File.Exist() func in c#, But even if the file is present it returns only as false.

Following is the sample code

```
outPath="\\DevSrv\\outPath\\result.txt";
if(File.Exists(outPath))
{
 .....
}
```

The above code always fails event the path "\DevSrv\outPath\result.txt" is valid. I am able to access the path using the windows explorer.

---

Sorry i missed the "\" while creating this post

Comment: Does it return false or do you get an exception?  If you get an exception that probably means that the caller does not have access to the path.

Comment: how about using verbatim string ?

Comment: @Stanley , It is returning false and there is no exception and when i browsed thru the windows explorer the path is accessible for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using strings with a backslash you need to think about escape sequence.
This link will give you a detailed view about the escape sequences.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available.aspx

Quote from link :

C# defines the following character escape sequences:

- \' - single quote, needed for character literals
- \" - double quote, needed for string literals
- \\ - backslash
- \0 - Unicode character 0
- \a - Alert (character 7)
- \b - Backspace (character 8)
- \f - Form feed (character 12)
- \n - New line (character 10)
- \r - Carriage return (character 13)
- \t - Horizontal tab (character 9)
- \v - Vertical quote (character 11)
- \uxxxx - Unicode escape sequence for character with hex value xxxx
- \xn[n][n][n] - Unicode escape sequence for character with hex value nnnn (variable length version of \uxxxx)
- \Uxxxxxxxx - Unicode escape sequence for character with hex value xxxxxxxx (for generating surrogates)

Of these, \a, \f, \v, \x and \U are rarely used in my experience.

So in your example. You can use the following options for your string.

```
outPath=@"\\DevSrv\outPath\result.txt";
//Or
outPath="\\\\DevSrv\\outPath\\result.txt";
```

Comment: Its the later. This is actual path i'm checking in the source \\olapserver\HISTDATA3111_UK\Flatfile_Output\20120809\201208090716224\201208090716224.zip

Comment: Is this run as a diffrent user when you are running the program? You could try this but not sure if it helps. FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"\\olapserver\HISTDATA3111_UK\Flatfile_Output\20120809\201208090716224\20120809071‌​6224.zip");
            if(file.Exists)
            {
                //Some code
            }

Answer (score 4):

Use `@` before your string for avoid having to escape slashes

```
outPath=@"\\DevSrv\outPath\result.txt";
if(File.Exists(outPath))
{
  .....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You aren't escaping the slashes, try:

```
outPath="\\\\DevSrv\\outPath\\result.txt";
if(File.Exists(outPath))
{
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between UNC and regular paths.

considuring having a file:

c:\temp\myFile.txt

Testing for

```
File.Exists(@"c:\temp\myFile.txt")
```

will return true.

But even the following (having double backslashes)

```
File.Exists(@"c:\temp\\myFile.txt")
```

returns true.

BUT using UNC + having doubleSlashes

```
File.Exists(@"\\?\c:\temp\\myFile.txt")
```

returns false

So - as many mentioned - using

```
Path.Combine()
```

is a good habit since it makes sure you don't have these double slashes.